# Can we use Visual Studio 2013 & Visual Studio 2015 simultaneously

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Generally it used to be happen that if any one version of Visual Studio is installed in any PC then installing another version of Visual Studio in the same PC will combine with each other.

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 to develop windows phone 8.0 apps, and now i also want to develop windows 10 Universal Apps for which i guess i need Visual Studio 2015 at least.

**So is it possible that i install and use VS2015 and VS2013 side by side..?**

PS - I've Windows 10 OS installed.

Thanks..

Comment: It is possible to install every version of Visual Studio.  They are independent of one another.  You don't have to do anything special in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: Answering with sole "yes" or "no" makes low-quality answer (and if the question induces such answers then maybe it's not a good question in the first place). If the answer is "yes" we should also answer "how?". If the answer is "no" then "why not?". We add links, citations and examples to support our claim.